# Laravel Form::Model Binding - PUT/PATCH Update Routing not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have routes set up to to create a person record as follows:

```
Route::get('bodymaker/create', 'BodyMakerController@create')->name('bodymaker.create');
Route::post('bodymaker', 'BodyMakerController@store')->name('bodymaker.store');
Route::get('bodymaker/{id}/edit', 'BodyMakerController@edit')->name('bodymaker.edit');
Route::put('bodymaker/{id}/update', 'BodyMakerController@update')->name('bodymaker.update');
Route::patch('bodymaker/{id}', 'BodyMakerController@update')->name('bodymaker.update');
```

The controller methods to generate a new record works properly and look like this:

```
public function create()
{
    return View::make('bodymaker.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person;

    $person->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $person->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $person->save();

    return View::make('person.store', ['person'=>$person]);
}
```

NOW... my problem is getting the edit/update form to bind properly...

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $person = Person::findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('person.edit', ['person'=>$person]);
}

public function update($id)  
{
// This route fails when I pass in the Request $request like in the store method. 
//But how does the update method receive the form values differently than the store method(?)
    $person = Person::findOrFail($id);

    $person->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $person->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $person->save();

    return View::make('person.update', ['person'=>$person]);
}
```

The form for the update looks like this

```
{{ Form::model($person, ['route' => ['person.edit', $person->id], 'method' => 'PUT'] }}

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {!!  Form::text('first_name'), Input::old('first_name')  !!}
        {!!  Form::text('last_name'), Input::old('last_name')  !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Update Person') !!}

{!!  Form::close()  !!}
```

I can't seem to get the form to update the record, only been able to generate a new record.  Something about the syntax for the Form::model binding that I'm not understanding. The PUT request is failing when I pass in the Request as an argument so I don't understand the difference between POST & PUT as used inside Laravel either, though I'm not sure that's my problem

Here is my artisan route:list

```
| web,auth |||GET|HEAD| bodymaker/{id}/edit  | bodymaker.edit  | App\Http\Controllers\BodyMakerController@edit                             
| web,auth |||PUT     | bodymaker/{id}/update| bodymaker.update| App\Http\Controllers\BodyMakerController@update
```

Answer (score 2):

Your controller `update` method signature should look like this, with `$request` as the first argument and `$id` as the second. And I consolidated some of the logic too, but this is optional.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $person = Person::findOrFail($id);
    $person->update($request->all());

    return view('person.update', compact('person'));
}
```

Also, not that it should matter, given that the URL structure is identical, but you're using the `person.edit` instead of the `person.update` route in your form defintion. But I see that you have two routes called `person.update`. One is for `PUT` and the other `PATCH`. You may want to be careful re-using the same route names.

Finally, if using the Laravel `Form` helpers, you don't need to add the `csrf_field()` yourself. This is added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are a little bit confused. First of all, you should be clear about how routes and resource controller work.

You can find important information to your undestanding here:
[Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers)

You can try this:

**routes.php**

```
Route::put('bodymaker/{id}', 'BodyMakerController@update')->name('bodymaker.update');
```

**controller.php**

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $person = Person::findOrFail($id);
    $person->update($request->all());

    return view('person.edit', compact('person'));
}
```

**form.blade.php**

```
{!!Form::model($person,['url'=> ['bodymaker',$person->id],'method'=>'PUT'])!!}

.... your form

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

As I can see you are only using the resource methods, therefore, I recommend to use a resourceful route with the same actions as listed in the link above, like this:

`Route::resource('bodymaker', 'BodyMakerController');`

Also, don't confuse the views (person) with the routes (bodymaker), because you're doing a mix of those.

Answer (score 0):

You should set  `method = "POST"` of the form.And the in the form add `{{method_filed('PUT')}}` when use `PUT` method.

The same with others.

Answer (score -1):

You should set `method = "POST"` of the form. And the in the form add `{{method_field('PUT')}}` when use PUT method.